# owlcarousel Permission denied to access property "apply"

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel-2

i'm using owlcarousel, version 2.3.4, jquery v 3.3.1, on C# Razor pages.
My carousel is initialized with this function:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   items: 4, 
   nav: true, 
   dots: false, 
   loop: true,
   responsive:{0:{items:1},651:{items:2},1401:{items:3},1601:{items:4}}       
})
```

On Chrome(v84.0.4147.89) it works well but on Firefox 68.10.0esr I caught this error on page resize:
Permission denied to access property "apply"

trigger owl.carousel.js:1571

onResize owl.carousel.js:713

i jQuery

Can someone help me to understand where is the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This error is related, in my case, to Firefox PX Viewport Dimensions Plugin; when I have deactivated the plugin the error disappeared.
If someother catch this error, try to deactivate all your installated Plugin to find whitch cause.